# efficient way to check for a string in a large text document in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a 30kb text file containing space delimited urls. I need to perform a check on the string entered by the user against the strings in the text file. What will be the most efficient way to accomplish this?

1. Create a Set in redis; perform sismember on the set for search.
2. Load the file inside a variable in nodejs server and perform indexOf operation (I think this will likely result in blocking!).
3. Some other method, I'm not aware of ...

(The file size could increase to max 80kb)

Comment: 30 kb is not large by any means. Redis? What are you talking about? That's a tiny, tiny file. Load it into RAM, split it at the space, done.

Comment: indexOf won't be a blocking operation at the size of ~50kb?

Comment: At what size would indexOf become blocking?

Comment: indexOf is *always* blocking, but it's also very fast. Make the minimum solution, measure its performance. If you have proof that it is too slow, think how to make it faster, measure again. Currently you are overengineering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I deal with 30 MB, 1 GB, 1TB files. 30KB sounds small but depending on circumstances, it can be very large. Imagine your server is very busy due to lots of visitors and you want to do that operation while there are many visitors, server will definitely experience heavy server load. I recommend to think about efficient algorithm or tool that can help you out with this.

Question: Why can't your data stay in Redis? You can easily do full text search from Redis side. If this can't be done, think about associating a full text search engine in your Node.js side or come up with an efficient search algorithm.

Here is what I would do:

Save words as index, for example you have this text:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Crawl this text and save each word and their location within the large text.

- `Lorem` is at `0`
- `Ipsum` is at `7`

If `Lorem` show up again in later text, just append to `Lorem` key (`Lorem: 0,118`)

Then you can easily search for keys and see if that word exists or not.